# Error linking LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0

Whenever I create two separate libraries with LLVM 3.0 and link them together. I always get the following stack trace on exit.

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000001004b0000
#0  0x00007fff8a95cda2 in memmove$VARIANT$sse42 ()
#1  0x00000001006020a0 in llvm::PassRegistry::removeRegistrationListener ()
#2  0x00000001005fbe60 in llvm::cl::list<llvm::PassInfo const*, bool, llvm::PassNameParser>::~list ()
#3  0x00007fff8a9767c8 in __cxa_finalize ()
#4  0x00007fff8a976652 in exit ()
```

I am creating one shared library from the Core component and one from the Target component.

I have tried calling:

```
LLVMPassRegistryRef pass_registry = LLVMGetGlobalPassRegistry();
LLVMInitializeCore(pass_registry);
```

Any ideas on how proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple solution in case anyone is wondering. The --enable-shared option (disabled by default) on the configure script creates a LLVM-3.X shared library. Linking to this rather than the output of the `llvm-config --libs core` solved it.